# using Array.Parallel.map for decreasing running time

Tags: f#, parallel-processing

#### Hello everyone

I have converted a project in C# to F# that paints the Mandelbrot set.
Unfortunately does it take around one minute to render a full screen so I am try to find some ways to speed it up.

It is one call that take almost all of the time:

```
Array.map (fun x -> this.colorArray.[CalcZ x]) xyArray
```

`xyArray (double * double) []`  => (array of tuple of double)
colorArray is an array of int32 length = 255

`CalcZ` is defined as:

```
 let CalcZ (coord:double * double) =

    let maxIterations = 255

    let rec CalcZHelper (xCoord:double) (yCoord:double) // line break inserted
           (x:double) (y:double) iters =
        let newx = x * x + xCoord - y * y
        let newy = 2.0 * x * y + yCoord
        match newx, newy, iters with
        | _ when Math.Abs newx > 2.0 -> iters
        | _ when Math.Abs newy > 2.0 -> iters
        | _ when iters = maxIterations -> iters
        | _ -> CalcZHelper xCoord yCoord newx newy (iters + 1)

    CalcZHelper (fst coord) (snd coord) (fst coord) (snd coord) 0
```

As I only use around half of the processor capacity is an idea to use more threads and specifically Array.Parallel.map, translates to [system.threading.tasks.parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx)

**Now my question**

A naive solution, would be:

```
Array.Parallel.map (fun x -> this.colorArray.[CalcZ x]) xyArray
```

but that took twice the time, how can I rewrite this to take less time, or can I take some other way to utilize the processor better?

Thanks in advance
Gorgen

**---edit---**
the function that is calling `CalcZ` looks like this:

```
          let GetMatrix =
            let halfX = double bitmap.PixelWidth * scale / 2.0
            let halfY = double bitmap.PixelHeight * scale / 2.0
            let rect:Mandelbrot.Rectangle = 
                {xMax = centerX + halfX; xMin = centerX - halfX;
                 yMax = centerY + halfY; yMin = centerY - halfY;}

            let size:Mandelbrot.Size = 
                {x = bitmap.PixelWidth; y = bitmap.PixelHeight}

            let xyList = GenerateXYTuple rect size
            let xyArray = Array.ofList xyList
            Array.map (fun x -> this.colorArray.[CalcZ x]) xyArray
        
        let region:Int32Rect = new Int32Rect(0,0,bitmap.PixelWidth,bitmap.PixelHeight)
        bitmap.WritePixels(region, GetMatrix, bitmap.PixelWidth * 4, region.X, region.Y);
```

GenerateXYTuple:

```
let GenerateXYTuple (rect:Rectangle) (pixels:Size) =
    let xStep = (rect.xMax - rect.xMin)/double pixels.x
    let yStep = (rect.yMax - rect.yMin)/double pixels.y
    [for column in 0..pixels.y - 1 do
       for row in 0..pixels.x - 1 do
         yield (rect.xMin + xStep * double row,
           rect.yMax - yStep * double column)]
```

**---edit---**

Following a suggestion from kvb (thanks a lot!) in a comment to my question, I built the program in Release mode. Building in the Relase mode generally speeded up things.

Just building in Release took me from 50s to around 30s, moving in all transforms on the array so it all happens in one pass made it around 10 seconds faster. At last using the Array.Parallel.init brought me to just over 11  seconds.

What I learnt from this is.... Use the release mode when timing things and using parallel constructs...
One more time, thanks for the help I have recieved.
**--edit--**
by using SSE assember from a native dll I have been able to slash the time from around 12 seconds to 1.2 seconds for a full screen of the most computational intensive points. Unfortunately I don't have a graphics processor...

Gorgen

Comment: I wrote some code to generate an image out of the data your function provides, and it only takes a few seconds to generate a 1920x1200 grayscale image.  Are you sure the problem isn't your rendering code? (Then again, FSI does seem to somehow make things run faster than normal...)

Comment: Running your code, at 1920x1200, with no drawing, I get an average over 20 runs of 452ms for the non-parallel version and 135ms for the parallel version, which is a speedup of about 3.4 on my 4-core Windows 7 VM. The same code run on my Ubuntu box on mono 2.8 has a non-parallel time of 743ms and very noisy times ranging from 35ms to 992ms for the parallel version. All times are measured with System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch. Are you averaging multiple runs to draw your conclusions? Are you on mono by any chance?

Comment: @Jason: No I am sitting on a Ebox with 1 GB mem with two cores. For measuring  I have measured  the time between Breakpoints I have VS2010Shell with F#

Comment: @Jason: I have measured non-parallel, parallel and non-parallel within parallel versions and in my measurements, the non-parallel have been the fastest, followed by the mixed version with the parallel slowest. I would very much see the code that you used for testing. Can you make an answer to this question and post the code? I suspect I have some shared variable or something that the threads have to access sequentially

Comment: If you're timing via breakpoints, does that imply that you're running in Debug mode?  If so, you'll find that your performance characteristics may change dramatically when running in Release mode...

Comment: @kvb: Yes, I was timing using breakpoints. And building in release mode made a around 40% improvment. :-) Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an aside, it looks like you're generating an array of coordinates and then mapping it to an array of results. You don't need to create the coordinate array if you use the `init` function instead of `map`: `Array.Parallel.init 1000 (fun y -> Array.init 1000 (fun x -> this.colorArray.[CalcZ (x, y)]))`

EDIT: The following may be inaccurate:
<strike>Your problem could be that you call a tiny function a million times, causing the scheduling overhead to overwhelm that actual work you're doing. You should partition the array into much larger chunks so that each individual task takes a millisecond or so. You can use an array of arrays so that you would call `Array.Parallel.map` on the outer arrays and `Array.map` on the inner arrays. That way each parallel operation will operate on a whole row of pixels instead of just a single pixel.</strike>

Comment: So it tries to make it's own task of every call to the function? I imagined that but I couldn't find anything about that on MSDN. And I will look into the init function, thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Gorgen: This shouldn't really be an issue. It _may be) better to have thousands of iterations, rather than millions (and it sounds logical), but in some tests I did, there wasn't any observable difference. But of course, the important advice when writing parallel code is to measure it yourself...

Comment: Tomas: You may be right. I was thinking of `ForEach` rather than `For`; I'm not sure how `For` works. Regardless, I believe my suggestions are good ideas.

Comment: I will take a closer look on this tomorrow, I have my wife behind my back as I write this... Yes, it is really a home project :)

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment on the original post, here is the code I wrote to test the function.  The fast version only takes a few seconds on my average workstation.  It is fully sequential, and has no parallel code.

It's moderately long, so I posted it on another site: http://pastebin.com/Rjj8EzCA

I'm suspecting that the slowdown you are seeing is in the rendering code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take a look on this as soon as I got time to spare. Pastebin seems like a nice tool too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the `Array.Parallel.map` function (which uses `Parallel.For` from .NET 4.0 under the cover) should have trouble parallelizing the operation if it runs a simple function ~1 million times. However, I encountered some weird performance behavior in a similar case when F# didn't optimize the call to the lambda function (in some way).

I'd try taking a copy of the `Parallel.map` function from the F# sources and adding `inline`. Try adding the following `map` function to your code and use it instead of the one from F# libraries:

```
let inline map (f: 'T -> 'U) (array : 'T[]) : 'U[]=
  let inputLength = array.Length
  let result = Array.zeroCreate inputLength
  Parallel.For(0, inputLength, fun i ->
    result.[i] <- f array.[i]) |> ignore
  result
```

Comment: I have tried your function but for some reason it is choking on the fact that I have an array of (double * double) at least I interpret the error message as that: 'c -> 'd     is not compatible with type     seq<'a * 'b>